# problem about view module in drupal 7

Tags: views

I have created a view for a content type called "events," and in the view there are 2 contextual filters (by category and years).

what I want to do is to be able to view the result in 3 conditions:

1. only the year:  http://example.com/events/2010
2. only the category ID:  http://example.com/events/4
3. year and category ID together:  http://example.com/events/2010/4

Now the problem is that in the second case, as the argument is considered a year.

How can I set the view to be able to use a URL as in the second case?

Comment: What do you do when the category id is 2010? You can't really do it like you suggest without doing custom code and risking things breaking.

Answer (score 2):

As @googletorp commented, the argument in the url have to keep a certain order if not Views won't know which kind it is. The recommended method for this is allowing a "wildcard" by providing an exception, in views you can configure this in the contextual filter options:
[image: contextual filters default arguments]
Then you simply put all instead of the year when not it's not available:
2- the category id alone : http://mydomain.com/events/all/4

Comment: Don't understand what should be entered instead of 'all'
in the textfiels "Exception value"

Comment: You just leave it as "all", then when you want to display the events for every year in a specific category you just call this URL: `http://mydomain.com/events/all/4`. Renaming this parameter allows you to localize it, for example: `http://mydomain.com/events/todos/4` in spanish.